# How many bytes long should nSequence be?

Tags: raw-transaction, sequence, checksequenceverify

When I look at the following raw transaction from: https://blockstream.info/tx/a175425ee2f3c01acc97ef32ab1082db14eaa94e5af4c54f02f3b01dec72558e?expand

```
020000000001018e5572ec1db0f3024fc5f45a4ea9ea14db8210ab32ef97cc1ac0f3e25e4275a100000000**00cf050000**01d2ddbc0000000000160014b82d832b2e5c0d80c771b06ce0da50fbccf12f3e0347304402204a54d94068512c22847cc07fa85f2b93feaf758411920a9b20ce9b85831e8aa5022005924cb82c331c5173e21477a4d8298eb25c0d967ace065b883455f2537c3d0a01004d632103f96d73ffe138690f032e97408af933a71782ad27a28df66a750b48c56b2d7fa96702cf05b275210304f332f50363cd01b679d9fb50fb8691fb0fb638737867bd02f06850c6191a2268ac00000000
```

When I parse it manually, specifically at this section: `a100000000**00cf050000**01...`

`a1` is the last byte of the input tx (in little endian),

`00000000` is the output index (4-bytes),

and at the end the `01` is the tx_out_count.

But that would make the sequence number **`00cf050000`**, which is longer than 4 bytes? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence number is always 4 bytes, it is a fixed size, little endian, 32 bit integer which makes it always 4 bytes.

What you are missing is the `scriptSig`. The `scriptSig` always begins with the size of the script (as a compact size unsigned integer). If the `scriptSig` is empty, then the size must still be there to say that it is a 0 length byte. So the first byte of your "sequence" is actually the length byte for the `scriptSig` that says it is of length 0.